# fix multiple elifs when checking element membership in different sets

Tags: python, python-3.x

Apologize if this is duplicate but I couldn't find a question that helped me figure out my exact problem so I thought I would give a shot at my first stack overflow post.

I have a **list** of strings and around 10 different **sets** of strings, and I want to do a different action based on which set each of the strings is in (for now, I can assume that the sets do not overlap). If it's not in any of them then I just continue. Right now I just have 10 if/elifs and it just seems a little inefficient and I was wondering if there's any way I could improve this?

To give an example:

```
sandwich_ingredients = ["bacon", "cheese", "bread", "lettuce", "car"]
vegetables = {"cucumber", "lettuce", "onion", "potato", "carrot"}
meats = {...}
carbs = {...}
dairy = {...}
for ingredient in pizza_ingredients:
    if ingredient in vegetables:
        print("veggie!")
    elif ingredient in meats:
        print("meat!")
    elif ingredient in carbs:
        print("carb!")
    elif ingredient in dairy:
        print("dairy!")
    else:
        continue
```

As you can see, if I had many more sets it gets a bit long and unwieldy... Also I'm not just printing out the name of the set, this is just an example to help show what I'm trying to figure out. :) Thank you very much for your help!

EDIT: I need to know which set it was found in hence the print example btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put all ingredience categories into a structure, and loop through them:

```
vegetables = {"cucumber", "lettuce", "onion", "potato", "carrot"}
meats = {...}
carbs = {...}
dairy = {...}
all_categories = {
    "vegetables": vegetables,
    "meats": meats,
    "carbs": carbs,
    "dairy": dairy,
}

for ingredient in pizza_ingredients:
    for category_name, category_items in all_categories.items():
        if ingredient in category_items:
            print(category_name)
```

if you don't need the `category_name`, define `all_categories` as a list instead of a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't know your sets are mutally exclusive. Hence, the elif's are needed. If you were willing to precompute their seperation by mapping elements to their set name, then you could remove the elif's. Like:

```
X = {1,2,3}
Y = 'abc'

ALL = {1:"X",2:"X",3:"X",'a':'Y','b':'Y','c':'Y'}

for i in ingredients:
    name_of_set = ALL[i]
```